# EF LINQ: How to exclude values of one table from another

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table called AnnualLeave in which the dates of holidays booked are stored.
I have another table called BankHolidays and this table supplies dates that make it impossible to book annual leave at the same time.
However sometimes an extra date is added to the BankHoliday table, for example for a Royal Wedding. When a new bank holiday is added, I could simply delete all annual leave on that day, but what if the date input is wrong? I want the administrator to be able to change that date without deleting annual leave that has already been booked.
So I think the solution is to keep AnnualLeave dates in the table, but every query of AnnualLeave should exclude BankHoliday dates.

In SQL this would be equivelent to a NOT IN clause, or a left outer join with a check for Null on the key field.

The question is how do I do this in EF4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
context.AnnualLeaves.Where(al => !context.BankHolidays.Any(bh => bh.Date == al.Date)).ToList();
```

It may depends on your approach to EF (Code First/POCO/Database First).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for that. I was looking at the Contains and Except clauses, but this one works.